# Hyperlink in SWF file published from captivate does not work

Tags: hyperlink, flash, adobe-captivate

I have published a Captivate 6 file in swf format. In one the slides is a button, that when clicked executed a small piece of javascript code to open a url , using the window.open command. This link opens fine, when i publish the project as a html5 output, ie mp4 file. however , when I publish it as swf, nothing happens on clicking the button. I read somewhere that flash security settings need to be updated and you need to add the folder where swf file is , as a trusted folder. I did that but still it does not work. Then I read that this problem comes only while developing since the flash player blocks access to local files and folder, so I published this swf on a web server on , but again same problem. Would be very grateful if anyone can provide some way to solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Captivate 7 and have had countless problems with javascript, but anyways... I'll avoid ranting about that.

When you publish it as an swf are you loading it from the .htm file? I've noticed that JavaScript only "worked"(haha, if you could...ok, no ranting..) by loading it in the .htm file. When I loaded the swf directly locally or from a web server it wouldn't work.

There are three or four files in Captivate 7: swf, htm, css, and js file.
When I put all of those on the web server, and load the .htm file JavaScript... uh, "worked'.. yeah